# Controller Targeting / Directory Routing

Tags: php, loops, url-routing, directory-structure

I am currently working with my Router class where I have this function that analyzes/parses the URI, and targets the controller, method, and arguments.

In this function, I have to target the actual controller which could be placed within a directory or bunch of subdirectories e.g. "other-category/some-directory/actual-controller.php".

Currently, I am manually checking it level by level where I have to put a conditional statement for each level.

**In this approach, the depth of the directory that could be possibly checked for the actual controller only depends on the number of the conditional statements. So I'm finding this a little messy and definitely limited.**

I'm thinking and searching for a better way to check this, something that I don't need to do those conditional statements. If you could help me end up with a better way, that would be greatly appreciated.

This is the part where I target the controller segment:

```
$this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);

// check if there's a first-level directory
if(is_dir(CONTROLLERPATH.$this->target_controller)){
    $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
    $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);
}

// check if there's a second-level directory
if(isset($this->dirs[0])){
    if(is_dir(CONTROLLERPATH.$this->dirs[0]."/".$this->target_controller)){
        $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
        $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);
    }
}       

// check if there's a third-level directory
if(isset($this->dirs[0]) && isset($this->dirs[1])){
    if(is_dir(CONTROLLERPATH.$this->dirs[0]."/".$this->dirs[1]."/".$this->target_controller)){
        $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
        $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);
    }
}

// check if there's a fourth-level directory
if(isset($this->dirs[0]) && isset($this->dirs[1]) && isset($this->dirs[2])){
    if(is_dir(CONTROLLERPATH.$this->dirs[0]."/".$this->dirs[1]."/".$this->dirs[2]."/".$this->target_controller)){
        $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
        $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);
    }
}
```

> The first line of code,in the above snippet , assigns the segment to
>   the target_controller property. Then the conditional statements below
>   will check if the actual controller is placed within a directory or
>   subdirectories e.g.
>   "other-category/some-directory/actual-controller.php".

Comment: The `$segments` array will always contain only the path to the controller and the controller or also may contain the action and parameters for the controller? For example: `$segments = array('other-category', 'some-directory', 'actual-controller', 'actual-action', 'id', '123')`.

Comment: Yes, the segments array also contain those stuffs. I have my code for targeting the method/action/arguments, and the code will only do it after detecting the actual controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If your segments are safe...

If your segments don't contain `..` which may lead to getting files outside `CONTROLLERPATH`, you can use the code below.

### Code

```
  $this->dirs = array (CONTROLLERPATH);
  while (count($segments) && is_dir(implode('/', $this->dirs).'/'.($element = array_shift($segments))))
  {
      $this->dirs[] = $element;
  }
  array_shift($this->dirs);
  $this->target_controller = $element;
```

### Demo

```
<?php

define('CONTROLLERPATH', './'); 

class A
{

    public function test()
    {
        $segments = explode('/', 'a/b/c/d/controller/action/argA/argB');
        $this->dirs = array (CONTROLLERPATH);
        while (count($segments) && is_dir(implode('/', $this->dirs) . '/' . ($element = array_shift($segments))))
        {
            $this->dirs[] = $element;
        }
        array_shift($this->dirs);
        $this->target_controller = $element;
    }

}


mkdir('./a/b/c/d', 0777, true);
$a = new A();
$a->test();
var_dump($a);
```

Returns:

```
class A#1 (2) {
  public $dirs =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "a"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "b"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "c"
    [3] =>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  public $target_controller =>
  string(10) "controller"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, I can't test the entirety of your code, but would something along the lines of this work? If we're looping, this code assumes that `$this->dirs[$i]` will always be set and all parent directories as well (at least, I'd think so).

```
<?php

$this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);

// check if there's a first-level directory
if (is_dir(CONTROLLERPATH . $this->target_controller)){
    $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
    $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->dirs); $i++) {
    if (is_dir(CONTROLLERPATH . implode("/", $this->dirs) . "/" . $this->target_controller)) {
        $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
        $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);
    }
}
```

**Another option is a do while loop**

Not quite sure how optimized this option is compared to the previous example.

```
<?php

$this->dirs = array();
$this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);

$counter = -1;

do {
    $implodedPath = implode("/", $this->dirs);

    if (is_dir(CONTROLLERPATH . $implodedPath . ((empty($implodedPath)) ? "" : "/") . $this->target_controller)) {
        $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
        $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments);
    }

    $counter++;
} while ($counter < count($this->dirs));
```

Comment: does the count($this->dirs) is updated after another element is added inside the loop?

Comment: Seems yes, I've tested it.. It shows incremented value on my logger every iteration. This works great :), I think I'm gonna wait for awhile, if there's anyone who could share another approach.

Comment: @reuelab Thinking about this question a bit more, could you try to see if my second example works?

Comment: Yes, the do while loop also works. But I think the first sample is better since it stores lesser variables? (I dont know if I am right about this).

Comment: @reuelab Neat! The second example was just a proof concept but I don't think the amount of variables with this little code would affect performance

Answer (score 1):

I like `for` loop:

```
$this->dirs = array(CONTROLLERPATH);

for($this->target_controller = array_shift($segments); 
    $this->target_controller !== null && is_dir(implode('/', $this->dirs).'/'.$this->target_controller);
    $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments)) 
{
    $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
}
```

**update:**

```
$current_path = CONTROLLERPATH;

for($this->target_controller = array_shift($segments); 
    $this->target_controller !== null && is_dir($current_path.'/'.$this->target_controller);
    $this->target_controller = array_shift($segments)) 
{
    $this->dirs[] = $this->target_controller;
    $current_path .= '/'.$this->target_controller;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This approach works, except setting the CONTROLLERPATH constant as first element of dirs array instead of placing the constant before the implode statement.